# Generate unique, comparable values

Tags: haskell, ghc

What's a good way to generate ad-hoc keys, where each key is unique to the program?  Ideally, an action of the form:

```
newKey :: IO Key
```

such that:

```
do a <- newKey
   b <- newKey
   return (a == b)
```

always returns false.  Also, it should be possible to use `Key` in an efficient associative container (e.g. a `Map`).

This could be used, for example, to maintain a collection of event handlers supporting random insertion and deletion:

```
Map Key EventHandler
```

Options I'm aware of:

- [`newIORef`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-IORef.html#v%3anewIORef)`()`: Satisfies the invariant above, but [IORef](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-IORef.html#t%3aIORef) doesn't have an Ord instance.
- [`malloc`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Foreign-Marshal-Alloc.html#v%3amalloc): Fast, and `Ptr ()` has an Ord instance, but the result is not garbage collected.
- [`newStablePtr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Foreign-StablePtr.html#v%3anewStablePtr)`()`: Not garbage collected, and [`StablePtr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Foreign-StablePtr.html) does not have an `Ord` instance.
- [`newIORef`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-IORef.html#v%3anewIORef)`() >>=`[`makeStableName`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Mem-StableName.html#v%3amakeStableName): Should satisfy the invariant above and is garbage collected, but more difficult to use (requires me to use a hash table).
- [`mallocForeignPtrBytes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.0.0/doc/html/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html#v%3amallocForeignPtrBytes)`1`: Satisfies both criteria, but is it efficient?

`mallocForeignPtrBytes 1` seems like my best option.  I suppose I could make it slightly more efficient by using GHC's `newPinnedByteArray#` primop directly.

Are there any better options?  Is the `mallocForeignPtrBytes` approach flawed for some non-obvious reason?

Comment: Another option: the uuid package on hackage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want to add any additional dependencies to your project, you can use [Data.Unique](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.4.1.0/Data-Unique.html) in the base package.

Internally, the system uses a [`TVar`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/stm/latest/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-STM-TVar.html) (which relies on GHC's STM system) of `Integer`s, such that every time you call `newUnique`, the `TVar` is incremented atomically, and the new `Integer` is stored in the opaque `Unique` data type. Because `TVar`s cannot be modified by different threads simultaneously, they guarantee that `Unique`s are generated in sequence, and that they must, in fact, be unique.

Comment: I'm slightly surprised that it isn't built on atomicModifyIORef, which I'd always thought was the fastest way to do relatively simple atomic operations.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Look at the source.  The comments explain why they didn't go that route: "using atomicModifyIORef would be slightly quicker, but can suffer from adverse scheduling issues (see [#3838](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3838))"

Comment: So that means values are unique across a single program's execution, but multiple instances of the program could generate the same "unique" values, right?

Comment: I accepted this answer because `Data.Unique` is pretty fast and is already available in base.  Although [newPinnedByteArray](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/primitive/0.4.0.1/doc/html/Data-Primitive-ByteArray.html#v:newPinnedByteArray) is faster, it is unlikely to make a difference in practice (or may even cause performance to vary wildly from run to run).  [See my benchmarks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8626077/149391).

Answer (score 5):

There are several relevant packages on hackage. The [concurrent-supply package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/concurrent-supply) looks to be quite carefully designed.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, dflemstr, for [pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8623123/149391) Data.Unique.  I benchmarked `Data.Unique` versus a couple alternative implementations:

#### Unique2.hs

Based on [mallocForeignPtrBytes](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.0.0/doc/html/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html#v:mallocForeignPtrBytes):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
module Unique2 (Unique2, newUnique2) where

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Typeable (Typeable)
import Data.Word (Word8)
import Foreign.ForeignPtr

newtype Unique2 = Unique2 (ForeignPtr Word8)
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Typeable)

newUnique2 :: IO Unique2
newUnique2 = Unique2 <$> mallocForeignPtrBytes 1
```

#### Unique3.hs

Based on [newPinnedByteArray](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/primitive/0.4.0.1/doc/html/Data-Primitive-ByteArray.html#v:newPinnedByteArray), which is used internally by [mallocForeignPtrBytes](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.0.0/doc/html/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html#v:mallocForeignPtrBytes).  It's basically the same as Unique2, minus some wrapper overhead.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
module Unique3 (Unique3, newUnique3) where

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Primitive.ByteArray
import Data.Primitive.Types
import Data.Typeable

newtype Unique3 = Unique3 Addr
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Typeable)

newUnique3 :: IO Unique3
newUnique3 = Unique3 . mutableByteArrayContents <$> newPinnedByteArray 1
```

#### unique-benchmark.hs

```
import Criterion.Main

import Control.Exception (evaluate)
import Control.Monad
import Data.Unique
import Unique2
import Unique3

import qualified Data.Set as S

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain
    [ bench "Unique" $
        replicateM 10000 newUnique  >>= evaluate . S.size . S.fromList
    , bench "Unique2" $
        replicateM 10000 newUnique2 >>= evaluate . S.size . S.fromList
    , bench "Unique3" $
        replicateM 10000 newUnique3 >>= evaluate . S.size . S.fromList
    ]
```

### Results:

Compiled with `ghc -Wall -O2 -threaded -fforce-recomp unique-benchmark.hs`:

```
benchmarking Unique
mean: 15.75516 ms, lb 15.62392 ms, ub 15.87852 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 651.5598 us, lb 568.6396 us, ub 761.7921 us, ci 0.950

benchmarking Unique2
mean: 20.41976 ms, lb 20.11922 ms, ub 20.67800 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 1.427356 ms, lb 1.254366 ms, ub 1.607923 ms, ci 0.950

benchmarking Unique3
mean: 14.30127 ms, lb 14.17271 ms, ub 14.42338 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 643.1826 us, lb 568.2373 us, ub 737.8637 us, ci 0.950
```

If I bump the magnitude from `10000` up to `100000`:

```
benchmarking Unique
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 21.26808 s
mean: 206.9683 ms, lb 206.5749 ms, ub 207.7638 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 2.738490 ms, lb 1.602821 ms, ub 4.941017 ms, ci 0.950

benchmarking Unique2
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 33.76100 s
mean: 319.7642 ms, lb 316.2466 ms, ub 323.2613 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 17.94974 ms, lb 16.93904 ms, ub 19.34948 ms, ci 0.950

benchmarking Unique3
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 21.22741 s
mean: 200.0456 ms, lb 199.2538 ms, ub 200.9107 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 4.231600 ms, lb 3.840245 ms, ub 4.679455 ms, ci 0.950
```

### Conclusion:

Data.Unique (the built-in implementation) and Unique3 (based on newPinnedByteArray) are neck and neck in these tests.  `newUnique3` itself is over ten times faster than `newUnique`, but key generation overhead is dwarfed by usage cost.

Unique2 loses due to wrapper overhead, but between Data.Unique and Unique3, my results are **inconclusive**.  I would recommend Data.Unique simply because it's already available in base.  However, if you're struggling to squeeze the last bit of performance out of some application, try substituting Data.Unique with Unique3, and tell me how it goes.

Comment: I think `Unique3` is unsafe, since the memory will be collected by the GC and reused, as you don't hold on to the array.

Answer (score 1):

One way I've seen if you want it at top level is with a hack like this:

```
import Data.IORef
import System.IO.Unsafe

newtype Key = Key Integer deriving (Ord, Eq, Show)

newKey :: IO Key
{-# NOINLINE newKey #-}
newKey = unsafePerformIO mkNewKey

mkNewKey :: IO (IO Key)
mkNewKey = do
  r <- newIORef 0
  return $ do
    modifyIORef r (+1)
    Key `fmap` (readIORef r)

main = do
  a <- newKey
  b <- newKey
  print (a,b)
```

Comment: This doesn't work when you have multiple threads that need unique values -- because `modifyIORef` might happen in parallel, you might get two identical `Key`s. Using `atomicModifyIORef` removes this problem, but can lead to inefficiencies.

Comment: @dflemstr, what inefficiencies?  `atomicModifyIORef` isn't expensive.

Comment: @luqui I thought I had read somewhere that `atomicModifyIORef` could lead to race conditions if overused (e.g. one thread performing atomic operations in a loop would occlude all other threads trying to access the particular `IORef`), but I can't seem to find the particular source for this claim.

Comment: @dfelmstr: See http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3838.  It looks like this issue is fixed; Data.Unique [uses atomicModifyIORef now](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Data-Unique.html#newUnique).